# Convergence of the derivative in Schwartz space

Tags: fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis, schwartz-space

Reading Grafakos' book "Classical Fourier Analysis", I got stuck in the Exercise $2.3.5.$ (a) which states that if $f ∈ \mathscr{S}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ then
$$(\tau^{−he_j} f − f )/h\rightarrow \partial_j f\qquad  \text{ in } \mathscr{S}(\mathbb{R}^n)\text{ as } h\rightarrow 0,$$
where $\tau^{−he_j} f(x) := f(x+he_j)$.

Could anyone give me some hints? I was thinking about a mean value argument. Thank you.

Comment: Can you show that it is valid pointwise?

Comment: @md2perpe Yes, this is direct since $\mathscr{S} (\mathbb{R}^n) \subset C^{\infty} (\mathbb{R}^n) $.

Comment: Isn't there a sign error in either $\tau^{−he_j} f(x) := f(x-he_j)$ or $(\tau^{−he_j} f − f )/h\rightarrow \partial_j f$?

Comment: What are your thoughts on what needs to be shown to show a limit in $\mathscr{S}(\mathbb{R}^n)$?

Comment: @md2perpe Yes, there is a sign change sorry. Regarding the second question, I would say 1.- $\partial_j f \in \mathscr{S}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ 2.- $\rho_{\alpha, \beta}((\tau^{-h e_j} f - f)/h - \partial_j f) \rightarrow 0$ as $h\rightarrow 0$ $\forall \alpha, \beta \in \mathbb{N}_0^n$. Maybe I'm mistaken.

Comment: Hint: $\tau^{-he_j}, \partial^\beta, \partial_j$ all commute in $\rho_{\alpha, \beta}((\tau^{-he_j}f-f)/h-\partial_j f)$ (after this a mean value argument should work)

Comment: Good, I'll try this. Thanks